# Подмена винительного падежа родительным

Tags: падежи, родительный-или-винительный

*Я не ставлю перед собой такие задачи.

Я не ставлю перед собой таких задач.*

Логика подсказывает, что падеж должен быть винительным (не ставлю кого/что?), а значит правильный вариант - первый.

С другой стороны, второй и ему подобные часто звучат лучше. Является ли это просторечием или языковой нормой?

Answer (score 4):

Эта тему можно посмотреть: §201. Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием.

[Розенталь. XLV. УПРАВЛЕНИЕ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm)

Коротко: Родительный падеж ― подчеркнутое отрицание, книжная речь, нейтральный стиль. Винительный падеж ― ослабленное отрицание, разговорный стиль. Кроме того, следует учесть влияние различных факторов, которые перечисляются в статье.

И теоретическая часть (по Грамматике-80)

Винительный беспредложный падеж показывает, что действие распространяется (переходит) на весь предмет полностью.  В. п. выступает как падеж прямого объекта при переходных глаголах.

Значение переходности утрачивается при отрицании, и тогда В. п. заменяется Р. п., таким образом выражается отсутствие прямого объекта. Поэтому Р. п. ― это классический падеж при отрицании (действие как бы доходит до границ предмета), но различные факторы могут ослаблять значение Р. п., и тогда как вариант может использоваться В. п.